# Olympic speed skating data, beyond final standings

Tags: data-request, sports

I'm looking for Olympic speed skating data, I have found many data sources providing the final standings (e.g. the official website: https://www.olympic.org/olympic-results).

However, I'm also interested in the order in which the athletes started, who they were paired with, what lane they started in (inner or outer), false starts and disqualifications. Does anyone know where I can find these data?

My interest isn't limited to the Olympic games only, data from other speed skating competitions would also be great.